# Ubuntu Linux sudo groupadd option menu keeps showing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, sudo

I'm a beginner to Ubuntu and Linux. Every time I try to do a groupadd in my Ubuntu terminal the options for groupadd show up and I dont know why.

I enter this in my home directory:

sudo groupadd –g 1125 groupname

Then I search for this and get nothing:

grep -i “groupname″ /etc/group

as well as this:

grep -i “1125" /etc/group

Why can't I make this group?

Comment: please update your question to include the command you ran and the output / error message.

Comment: Well the command is sudo groupadd –g 1125 groupname. The weird part is I don't get an exit value or an error, I get an options menu every time.

Comment: Try running `echo $?` after to see the exit status. `man groupadd` has a description of what the errors mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you copy and paste that from?  If that is the exact command you are using then your problem is that your `–` is not actually a hyphen, that is a dash character.  I am betting you copied from a blog or MS office or something, which automatically changed the hyphen to a unicode dash.

Heck just adjust the zoom level of your browser and look at the difference between the `-` used in your `sudo -i` and the `–` used in your `groupadd –g`.  They are different lengths and widths (assuming you aren't using some unusual font).

Comment: Wow, you're right. I copied it from a tutorial blog somewhere, I guess I learned my lesson. I'd upvote you but I have no reputation unfortunately. Edit: Upvoted!